# Lazy argument evaluation for try_emplace?

Tags: c++, c++17

Im in need of an object that can wrap a lazy initialization for a try_emplace with map (in effect calling a factory type of function only when needed), so that the following will convert ok in `try_emplace`:

```
std::map<std::string, bool> cache_;
cache_.try_emplace("hello", lazy_wrapper([]{return true;}));
```

*or perhaps*

```
std::map<std::string, whatever_wrapper<bool> > cache_;
cache_.try_emplace("hello", []{return true;});
```

I imagine that should be possible, but mainly on the lookout for an off-the-shelf solution (eg. `std` / `boost`) compared to rolling my own wrapper.

Comment: What'd you try?

Comment: I tried provide the lambda naked, that ofc. didnt compile. I guess it's easy enough to make a class type that will convert, but like I said im mostly interested if an off-shelf solution already exists.

Comment: Alas in a perfect (forwarding) world; [_P0927R0: Towards A (Lazy) Forwarding Mechanism for C++_](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p0927r0.pdf).

Comment: In terms of laziness, do you mean that the function doesn't get called unless the key is not present in the map?

Comment: @NicolBolas thats correct

Answer (score 3):

The following is a hand-made solution i just threw together in a few minutes, that does the job, but Im mostly on the lookout for some kind of off-the-shelf solution:

```
template<class F>
struct lazy_wrap {
    F f_;
    lazy_wrap(F&& f) : f_(f) {}
    template<class T>
    operator T() {
        return f_();
    }
};
```

Comment: This will evaluate `f` each time to get a `T`, I wouldn't call that "lazy"

Comment: Oh, this is for `std::map<std::string, bool>`, not `std::map<std::string, lazy_wrap<bool>>`

Answer (score 1):

You ultimately will have to implement the try-emplace logic yourself, since there's no simple function to do it.

```
template<typename Map, typename Key, typename Func>
auto lazy_try_emplace(Map &map, const Key &key, Func f)
{
    auto it = map.find(key);
    if(it == map.end())
      return map.emplace(key, f());
    return std::pair(it, false);
}
```

Yes, this looks up the element twice, but there's no way to avoid that without actually being part of the `std::map` implementation (which is why `try_emplace` exists at all). Search time could be minimized by replacing `map.find` with `map.lower_bound`, changing the conditional test to see if the key is not equal to `key`, and using `emplace_hint` with that iterator.

Comment: you can do lower_bound, check with == and in case there is no element use that as hint? Ugly as hell but should be faster in theory, no?

Answer (score -1):

Do you really need a wrapper? You could do this instead:

```
// C++20
if (!cache_.contains("hello"))
    cache_.emplace("hello", [] { return true; });

// pre C++20
if (cache_.count("hello") == 0)
    cache_.emplace("hello", [] { return true; });
```

Simple, clear, no headache.

Comment: this does a double lookup

Comment: I dont *really need* a wrapper as you say (map.find works too) - but it's more expressive that way with one line of code. On the same token we don't *need* try_emplace in the first place.